# How to regex replace all dots in text with spaces but exclude urls?

Tags: javascript, regex

The regex I have:

```
(?<!www)(\.+)

Dot. www.site.org word.
Dot. www.site.site.org word.
Dot. www.site.site.org word. D.C.
```

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/dvquhh/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your URLs either start with `http://` or `https://` or `www.`, you may use this regex with a negative lookbehind in Javascript:

```sh
(?<!\b(?:https?:\/\/|www)\S*)\.
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dvquhh/3)

**Code:**

```
repl = str.replace(/(?<!\b(?:https?:\/\/|www)\S*)\./g, ' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can replace all dot chunks not inside URLs with a single space using a regex like

```js
text = text.replace(/((?:https?:\/\/|www\.)\S*)|\.+/g, function(x, y) {
  return y ? y : " ";
})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MvbKvX/1)

The point is to match URLs and capture them into a capturing group, and match all other dots without capturing, and replace with the backreference pointing to the capturing group value.

This approach works in all browsers including Safari and IE.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
var text = "Dot. www.site.org word.\nDot. www.site.site.org word.\nDot. www.site.site.org word. D.C.";
text = text.replace(/((?:https?:\/\/|www\.)\S*)|\.+/g, function(x, y) {
  return y ? y : " ";
});
console.log(text);
```